# calculate number of true (or false) elements in a bool array?

Tags: c#, arrays, boolean

Suppose I have an array filled with Boolean values and I want to know how many of the elements are true.

```
private bool[] testArray = new bool[10] { true, false, true, true, false, true, true, true, false, false };

int CalculateValues(bool val)
{
    return ???
}
```

CalculateValues should return 6 if val is true, or 4 if val is false.

Obvious solution:

```
int CalculateValues(bool val)
{
    int count = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i<testArray.Length;i++)
    {
        if(testArray[i] == val)
            count++;
    }
    return count;
}
```

Is there an "elegant" solution?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Use LINQ. You can do `testArray.Where(c => c).Count();` for true count or use `testArray.Where(c => !c).Count();` for false check

Comment: While it's the same idea, the below answers using the conditional overload of count are cleaner.

Answer (score 58):

```
return testArray.Count(c => c)
```

Answer (score 16):

You can use:

```
int CalculateValues(bool val)
{
    return testArray.Count(c => c == val);
}
```

This handles the `true` and `false` checks, based on your `val` parameter.

Answer (score 3):

While `testArray.Count(c => c)` is functionally correct, it's not intuitive and there's a risk that some later developer will strip out the `c => c` part thinking it doesn't do anything.

This can be derisked by declaring the lambda function separately with a meaningful name:

```
Func<bool, bool> ifTrue = x => x;
return testArray.Count(ifTrue);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this :

```
bool[] testArray = new bool[10] { true, false, true, true, false, true, true, true, false, false };
bool inVal = true;
int i;

i = testArray.Count(ai => ai == inVal);
```

Answer (score -2):

I like this:

```
int trueCount = boolArray.Sum( x  => x ? 1 : 0 ) ;
```

Comment: Why repurpose `Sum` to perform the function of `Count`?

Comment: Because it's simpler, more concise and to the point. If you like `Where()`/`Count()`, you get the same results at the expense of an additional method call per array element.

Comment: I'd say `int trueCount = boolArray.Count(x => x)` is much more concise and to the point

Comment: According to the documentation, `Count()` "Returns the number of elements in a sequence." That will give you the count of the number of elements in the array or in the `IEnumerable<T>`, regardless of the element's _value_: you need to filter the sequence with `Where()` prior to applying `Count()`.

Comment: The `.Count()` method on a collection does, yes.  The `.Count` extension method in LINQ can take a filter: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534807(v=vs.110).aspx