# Cycle and access Method's parameters value

Tags: c#, parameters, .net-4.0, getparameter, methodbase

I have the following Method (I *exemplify* what I need in the **comments** of the method):

```
public static Dictionary<int, int> Foo(bool os, bool rad, bool aci, bool outr, string distrito = null)
{
    if (os == false && rad == false && aci == false && outr == false)
    {
        return new Dictionary<int, int>();
    }

    var parameters = MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().GetParameters();
    foreach (ParameterInfo parameter in parameters)
    {
        // I would love if parameter.Value existed, because:
        // if (parameter.Value==true) {
        // x++
        // if (x == 1) string s = "true" + parameter.Name;
        // if (x > 1) s += "Additional true" + parameter.Name;
        // }
        // s += "End";
    }
    return null;
}
```

I have to know if **one or more** values of the `bool` parameters are true. Since they are four, imagine the combination of `if` I would have to do to check if only one is true, or if more than one, which are true.

So, how can I cycle the current value of the incoming Method parameters without using the parameter variable itself?

Comment: It really depends on what you are trying to do. However, whenever you come across a scenario like this, it usually means you have to take a step back and rethink your design. A little bit more insight on the requirements might help. As you describe it, you can just do an OR (||) of all the values and you should get what you need but I have a feeling there is more to it than that.

Comment: without knowing context....I would use bitarray or array of bools. and use linq to determine if only one is true or even how many is true.

Comment: I updated the question and added my logic in the comments of the method. Essentially each `bool` represent a `WHERE` in SQL Select. If it is the first `true`, it's one query syntax. For the additional `true`, adds to original syntax but is another syntax (hence know if is 1st `bool`or more).

Comment: Are you only interested in the count of values that are true or do you need the name of the parameter as well?

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to know how many are true, you can turn them into integers and add their values:

```
var values = new[] {os, rad, aci, outr};
var sum = values.Select(v => Convert.ToInt32(v)).Sum();
```

If you need the name of the parameters, then you can create an anonymous object and read its properties:

```
public static Dictionary<int, int> Foo(bool os, bool rad, bool aci, bool outr, string distrito = null)
{
    var obj = new { os, rad, aci, outr};
    foreach (PropertyInfo pInfo in obj.GetType().GetProperties())
    {
        var value = (bool)pInfo.GetValue(obj);
        if (value)
        {
            //Do whatever you want here.                    
            Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", pInfo.Name, value);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Am i wrong or you just answered my question? I guess `ProperyInfo` + `GetValue()` is what i am looking for. I'm testing it now.

Comment: Well it only determines if has value, either `true` or `false`, and i need to know which of them are `true`/`false`.

Comment: Read the code one more time. It does exactly what you want. PInfo will have the name of the property that has value true.

Answer (score 0):

You can try some [`LINQ` extensions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11730919/213550), I think composition of [`Where`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.where.aspx) and [`Select`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.select.aspx) may be a solution, with a [`string.Join`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783876.aspx) method on top:

```
// get all parameters
var parameters = MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().GetParameters();

// for each true parameter we add this prefix
var truePrefix = "true";

// we put this string between true parameters, if more than one are present
var separator = "Additional";

// Join IEnumerable of strings with a given separator
var total = string.Join(separator, parameters
  // filter parameters to check only boolean ones, and only true ones
  .Where(p => p.ParameterType == typeof(bool) && (bool)p.Value)
  // select a name with prefix
  .Select(p => truePrefix + p.Name)))
```